# Lua OOP grid class with event

Tags: oop, events, lua, grid, coronasdk

I'm learning lua and i'm trying the OOP approach.
To start, I'm trying to make a grid class, but I think i'm still lacking some knowledge to make it do what I want it to do.

This is my code so far:

```
local screen = require( 'data.screen')
Grid = {}
Grid_mt = { __index = Grid }



--- Constructs a new Grid object.
function Grid:new(  params )

    local self = {}

    local function try( self, event )
        print(self.empty)
    end

    for i = 1, screen.tilesAcross do
        if not self[i] then 
            self[i] = {};
        end

        for j = 1, screen.tilesDown do

            self[i][j] = display.newImageRect( params.group, "images/playable.png", screen.tileWidth, screen.tileHeight )
            self[i][j].x = (j - 1) * (screen.tileWidth + screen.tileSpacing) + screen.leftSpacing
            self[i][j].y = (i - 1) * (screen.tileHeight + screen.tileSpacing) + screen.topSpacing
            self[i][j]._x = i
            self[i][j]._y = j
            self[i][j].enable = false
            self[i][j].empty = true

            self[i][j].tap = try

            self[i][j]:addEventListener( "tap", self[i][j] )

        end
    end


    setmetatable( self, Grid_mt )

    return self

end


function Grid:setEnable(value, x, y)
    if value ~= true and value ~= false then
        error("Boolean expected")
    end
    self[x][y].enable = value 
end

function Grid:getEnable(x, y)
    return self[x][y].enable
end

function Grid:setEmpty(value, x, y)
    if value ~= true and value ~= false then
       error("Boolean expected")
    end
    self[x][y].empty = value 
end

function Grid:getEmpty(x, y)
    return self[x][y].empty
end

function Grid:SetmColor()
    self[1][4]:setFillColor( 255,255 )
end
```

I have 2 questions:
My event works but I would like to do something like: print(self:getEmpty() )
but whenever I try to use a method in my event, it doesn't work "attempt to call method 'getEmpty' (a nil value)"

and also the setfillcolor wwon't work, I want to be able to change the color of a case with it.

Thanks for your time!
and if i'm going to the wrong road, let me know, and by the way, I have a working code without make a class, this is just for training purpose :)

Thnaks!

Comment: `if value ~= true and value ~= false then` can be written as `if type(value) ~= "boolean" then`

Comment: Can you show where you're trying to use `print(self:getEmpty() )`

Comment: Not a true answer, but you might be interested in this OOP open-source library for Lua / Corona:
https://github.com/TeddyEngel/Luoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `self[i][j]` is not a `Grid`, only `self` is a `Grid`. So when the event handler is called, `self` in the handler is the display object, not the `Grid` object. If the handler needs to know the grid object, you could assign the grid to each display object:

```
self[i][j].grid = self
```

then in `try` you could do

```
grid = self.grid
```

But in this case you may get a cleaner design if you have the tap handler not be specific to each display object. In this case you would use an upvalue, you can just use `self`:

```
function Grid:new(  params )

    local self = {}

    local function try( event ) -- omit the first param, self is an upvalue
        print(self.empty)
    end

    for i = 1, screen.tilesAcross do
        ...
        for j = 1, screen.tilesDown do

            self[i][j] = display.newImageRect( ... )
            ...
            self[i][j]:addEventListener( "tap", try )

        end
    end
```

Since listener given is a function rather than a table, it gets only one parameter, the event, and self is an upvalue so it will be the Grid instance created just above the `try` function.

Comment: ok, i have another question now that it's working:
is there a way to call my methode like this in my main
grid[x][y]:method(value) instead of gid:method(value, x,y)

Comment: @Néocypher not sure what you mean; sounds like a separate question, please post a new question

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, more information would be needed. See my [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152702/lua-oop-grid-class-with-event/24153351#comment37274304_24152702).

As for the `setFillColor` not working, the following is taken from [the Corona docs](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/ShapeObject/setFillColor.html):

```
object:setFillColor( gray )
object:setFillColor( gray, alpha )
object:setFillColor( red, green, blue )
object:setFillColor( red, green, blue, alpha )
object:setFillColor( gradient )
```

> `gray, red, green, blue, alpha` (optional)
>
> **Numbers between 0 and 1** that represent the corresponding
>   value for that channel. alpha represents the opacity of the object.

---

Now, when you are trying to execute:

```
self[1][4]:setFillColor( 255,255 )
```

you are passing the values for `gray` and `alpha` channels. The values **NEED TO BE** less than, or equal to **`1`**. Probably you want to pass `1` (as 255 is generally the max. value)

Comment: After some try, 255 and 1 give the same result, i'll keep using 1 though, since it look like the correct thing to do