# Lua classes interacting between themselves

Tags: class, oop, lua, interaction

I have yet another question in my learning of the OOP aspect of the lua and I can't seem to find the solution by myself.

I have 2 classes: the first one is a grid class that you can see here:

[My grid class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152702/lua-oop-grid-class-with-event/24155200)

And I have another class named player:

```
require('scripts.character.Character')
require('scripts.grid.Grid')
local screen = require( 'data.screen')
Player = {}
Player_mt = { __index = Player }

--- Constructs a new Character object.


function Player:new(  params )

    local self = {}

    setmetatable( self, Player_mt )

    -- Create the player visual
    self._visual = display.newImageRect( params.group, "images/player.png", screen.tileWidth, screen.tileHeight )
    self.types = "player"

    local function try( event)

       --I'm trying to use a grid method here!
    end


    self._visual.tap = try
    self._visual:addEventListener( "tap", self._visual )


    return self

end

setmetatable( Player, Character_mt )
```

and I've added a method in my grid class:

```
function Grid:resetColor()
    for x = 1, screen.tilesAcross  do
        for y = 1, screen.tilesDown do
            grid:setColor(x, y)
        end
    end
end
```

I'm thinking that I can't do that in player because I don't have a grid object that player can acces to.

In my main, I use my grid class like this:

```
local grid = Grid:new({group = gridgroup})
```

And player like this:

```
character[i][j] = Player:new( { group = playergroup}  )
```

How can I connect the 2, to be able to acces my grid from player, i've tried several thing, like putting grid as global or passing the grid as parameter but everything failed.

Thanks a lot again!

Comment: You want to be able to get access to the grid object the play is on/part of from the player object itself? Both setting the grid as a global and passing the grid to the Player:new function (and storing it in the player object) should work for that (with different trade-offs).

Comment: I did try both way but neither worked.
Setting the grid as global in my main: grid = Grid:new({group = gridgroup})
but then grid is always nil inside player for some reason.

and then trying to create a player like this:character[i][j] = Player:new( { group = playergroup, _grid = grid}  )
give me a grid and I can acces the method using self.grid:resetColor()

But then grid:setColor(x, y) inside the reset color gives me attempt to index global 'grid' (a nil value)

Comment: You don't want to use `grid:setColor` inside the `Grid:resetColor` function. You want to use `self:setColor` to use the grid that called the function. That's what the `:` syntactic sugar is hiding/allowing you there.

Comment: working now! thanks ^^
I wish I could tag it as an answer :o

Comment: I actually think this might be more suited to be closed as "simple typo" since had you not made the `grid` vs. `self` error your earlier attempts likely would have worked correctly.